# Linux cannot find the grpc_csharp_plugin executable when generating proto files?

Tags: c#, linux, protocol-buffers, grpc

I'm still fairly new to linux and also grpc/protobuf in general. Currently I am trying to make a grpc server client, using C#.

Currently I am having issues generating the grpc files at the moment. I think it's something to do with not having the actual executable for the plugin in the correct place. But I am not sure where this should be, or even how to navigate to that location.
Any and all help is appreciated, especially if there's any more information on grpc and generating proto files in general.

Original Command:

`protoc -I proto/ --grpc_out=grpc --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=grpc_csharp_plugin SimpleEnvMessages.proto`

Error Message:

`grpc_csharp_plugin: program not found or is not executable --grpc_out: protoc-gen-grpc: Plugin failed with status code 1.`

Comment: See [gRPC for .NET](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/csharp/dotnet/). I'm unsure but it may be that there's no standalone (i.e. `protoc_grpc_chsarp_plugin`) to use with `protoc` and you must use the regular C# tooling.

Comment: The protoc command you used seems mostly correct, but you have to check whether the grpc_csharp_plugin binary is executable (`ls -l grpc_csharp_plugin` and `chmod u+x grpc_csharp_plugin` if not) and it's really available in the current directory or the path provided (this is what the error message is complaining about).   Alternatively, you can use the Grpc.Tools nuget package that provides automatic codegen as part of your build (so that you don't have to compose the protoc commads by manually).

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same issue and that is that the grpc_csharp_plugin could not be found. I was using Pop! OS 22.04 and it seems like the grpc-proto packages was not shipping with the grpc plugin for C#.

What I did was, head of to Nuget Gallery and obtained the [Grpc.Tools nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Grpc.Tools) package extracted it to find the plugin under tools/linux_x64/.

Protoc could not find it under PATH so I just provided the directory to where I extracted it.